# If "orphanRemoval=true" is set, and the parent FK column is set to Not Null is false, when the child is persisted, it will be removed?

Tags: jpa

Let me copy my reference from [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/):

> ### Orphan Removal in Relationships
>
> When a target entity in one-to-one or one-to-many relationship is removed from the relationship, it is often desirable to cascade the remove operation to the target entity. Such target entities are considered “orphans,” and the orphanRemoval attribute can be used to specify that orphaned entities should be removed. For example, if an order has many line items and one of them is removed from the order, the removed line item is considered an orphan. If orphanRemoval is set to true, the line item entity will be deleted when the line item is removed from the order.
>
> The orphanRemoval attribute in @OneToMany and @oneToOne takes a Boolean value and is by default false.
>
> The following example will cascade the remove operation to the orphaned customer entity when it is removed from the relationship:
>
> ```
> @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", orphanRemoval="true")
> public List<Order> getOrders() { ... }
> ```

So, it suggests that **if we have `orphanRemoval=true`, when we remove the relationship of `@OneToOne` or `@OneToMany`, the orphans will be deleted.**

Now, if in the table of child, the column of FK of parent is set to `NN = false`, or, we can do insert of child without indicating its father, there is no relationship upon inserting. So, the child can be inserted successfully?

Or, in another words, can I understand that `orphanRemoval=true` forbids any children without parent in DB?

Comment: The row will be created, so? The insert / persist operation does not have to do anything with `orphanRemoval`. It does not automatically inserts the corresponding child entity into the inverse collection holding a list of children on the inverse side of the relationship unless you are explicit making that relationship bidirectional yourself manually which the JPA provider is not responsible for. Further, `orphanRemoval` disregards table relationships in the underlying database.

Comment: So, you imply when we do INSERT, this attribute does nothing?

Comment: Yes. You will have to add the owner to the inverse collection yourself manually. (it is not mandatory for the JPA provider to maintain bidirectional relationships though some providers may support this feature - it is not specified in the JPA specification).

Comment: OK make your comment as answer and I accept it. I understand you mean "Yes, it does nothing."